# Decoding polymorphic JSON objects into elm with andThen

Tags: json, elm

My JSON looks similar to this:

```
{ "items" : 
  [ { "type" : 0, "order": 10, "content": { "a" : 10,  "b" : "description", ... } }
  , { "type" : 1, "order": 11, "content": { "a" : 11,  "b" : "same key, but different use", ... } }
  , { "type" : 2, "order": 12, "content": { "c": "totally different fields", ... } }
   ...
  ] 
}
```

and I want to use the `type` value to decide what union type to create while decoding. So, I defined alias types and decoders for all the above in elm :

```
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing (..)

type alias Type0Content = { a : Int, b : String }
type alias Type1Content = { a : Int, b2 : String }
type alias Type2Content = { c : String }
type Content = Type0 Type0Content | Type1 Type1Content | Type2 Type2Content
type alias Item = { order : Int, type : Int, content: Content }

decode0 = succeed Type0Content
    |> requiredAt ["content", "a"] int
    |> requiredAt ["content", "b"] string
decode1 = succeed Type1Content
    |> requiredAt ["content", "a"] int
    |> requiredAt ["content", "b"] string
decode2 = succeed Type2Content
    |> requiredAt ["content", "c"] string
decodeContentByType hint =
    case hint of
        0 -> Type0 decode0
        1 -> Type1 decode1
        2 -> Type2 decode2
        _ -> fail "unknown type"
decodeItem = succeed Item
    |> required "order" int
    |> required "type" int `andThen` decodeContentByType
```

Can't get the last two functions to interact as needed.
I've read through page 33 of json-survival-kit by Brian Thicks, but that didn't bring me on track either.

Any advice and lecture appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the book was written targeting Elm 0.17 or below. In Elm 0.18, the [backtick syntax was removed](http://elm-lang.org/blog/the-perfect-bug-report#less-syntax). You will also need to use a different field name for `type` since it is a reserved word, so I'll rename it `type_`.

Some annotations might help narrow down bugs. Let's annotate `decodeContentByType`, because right now, the branches aren't returning the same type. The three successful values should be mapping the decoder onto the expected `Content` constructor:

```elm
decodeContentByType : Int -> Decoder Content
decodeContentByType hint =
    case hint of
        0 -> map Type0 decode0
        1 -> map Type1 decode1
        2 -> map Type2 decode2
        _ -> fail "unknown type"
```

Now, to address the `decodeItem` function. We need three fields to satisfy the `Item` constructor. The second field is the type, which can be obtained via `required "type" int`, but the third field relies on the `"type"` value to deduce the correct constructor. We can use `andThen` (with pipeline syntax as of Elm 0.18) after fetching the `Decoder Int` value using Elm's `field` decoder:

```elm
decodeItem : Decoder Item
decodeItem = succeed Item
    |> required "order" int
    |> required "type" int
    |> custom (field "type" int |> andThen decodeContentByType)
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that `required` and `custom` belongs to `Json.Decode.Pipeline`. If you want to stick to the core package, you can use `map3` and `field` instead.

Comment: Thank you to Chad and Chris for the solution and helpful explanations. I find it distrubing to find so many pre-0.18 tutorials and even the new explanations for `Decode.Pipeline.custom` were not helpful. Your description helped much more.